# Older Version of Chrome for OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Oldapps and filehippo both don't have OS X apps (at least Chrome)

Old version doesn't either....

I need to test 17x through 20x in order to reproduce a bug and can't find these browsers!

Where can I download them? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filehillo](http://www.filehippo.com/mac/download_google_chrome_for_mac/history) is a great repository, but chrome does try to update itself, so you may have to block the auto-update somehow

updated with new repository, as oldapps seems to have pulled many older versions

Comment: Please read my post.... I said OS X, not windows....

Comment: edited link for Mac - versions available for OSX 10.7, 10.6 and 10.5

Comment: Anyone figure this out on how to isolate and block the updating on first boot?

Comment: @Nick, try https://support.google.com/installer/answer/147176?hl=en&ctx=go

Comment: Is there an another repository? I went to oldapps, but it said it no longer stores old versions of Chrome.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, updated - I don't know what happened with oldapps